# More efficient way to run this on() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm running a function every time the user clicks, scrolls or moves the mouse. Clearing and setting an interval all the time seems like a lot to do since I guess the mousemove and scroll generates hundreds of actions all the time, meaning that it clears and sets it hundreds of times? Is there a better way of doing this, or is it in fact a piece of cake for the browser to perform? timerFunction() is not shown here, but if that matters, I can provide more code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    idleInterval = setInterval(timerFunction, 5000);

    $(this).on('click dblclick mousemove keypress scroll', function (e) {
        clearInterval(idleInterval);
        idleInterval = setInterval(timerFunction, 5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: what is $(this)? does that element has a selector?

Comment: Do you just think it’s a lot to do or did you measure it and determine that it was a performance problem?

Comment: You can check scroll periodically using an interval instead of watching the event, but there's not you can do about `mousemove` event.

Comment: There is no issue.

Comment: And: what does `timerFunction` do?

Comment: I suspect that you are asking for `debounce()` a.k.a. throttling of function calls: https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Updated code. Added the document ready.

Comment: @Ryan Yeah I don't have any performance issues (yet). I just imagine it being a lot to check every single time. If you guys think I'm good, I'll keep it, but if it's worth looking into throttling/debounce, I'm open to it. timerFunction fetches data with $.ajax(), but only x seconds not as often as the check for movements.

Comment: @c-smile Yes, do you think it's worth it it this case?

Comment: so you mean you are adding these events to the document?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I'm checking user activity on the whole page. Isn't $(document).on() the same as $(this).on() in this case? Any other way I should do it?

Comment: Yes in your case it is the same as $(document).on(). In my answer below, I assumed you have many elements such as divs and you are adding events to each one of them. My solution was to use one function to replace that

Comment: by the way, if you are setting the function only once it wouldn't create the function repeatedly, in case that is what you are worried about. In js function work as variables. Any function taking another function as a parameter would just store it and call it as and when needed.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane No, I'm just checking the overall user activity and fetches data via timerFunction with $.ajax() every x seconds and places that data on the page with the code inside the timerFunction. I don't need to attach the function to multiple elements. I guess it was confusing leaving out the document ready part in my first post. Basically my question is if it's worth to put a debouncer/throttle in there or not, if the mouseevents and scrolls sets and unsets the setinterval hundreds of times per seconds and if that is inefficient.

Comment: Here is a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zdbvKa?editors=1111) of your code *plus* a display of the amount of events... I really think there is no performance issue with this.

Comment: There is no performance issue with the common practice of clearing an interval on events... Event if there a lot of events. It will be hard to find a device not able to handle this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function only created once, you can use this:

```
$(document).on('click dblclick mousemove keypress scroll', '.myClass', function (e) {
    clearInterval(idleInterval);
    idleInterval = setInterval(timerFunction, 5000);
});
```

Each time you want this function inside an element, just add the `myClass` class to $(this) when you want to use it.

If your timerFunction is going to be different each time, you can store them into an array and map them.

Comment: Isn't the function already created only once? (Wouldn't `this` be `document` in the code shown?)

Comment: yes it will. I had posted this code before the question update. In the original question the `$(document).ready` part wasn't shown and none of us knew that he was trying to update the document element.

Answer (score 0):

First thing pops in my mind is this: you declare a boolean value on global scope and set it to `true` when desired event happens. Then you check the changes on that boolean on specific time interval, say 100 ms. I think this is an optimize way.

```js
var thatHappend = false;
$('#sample').on('click dblclick mousemove keypress scroll', function (e) {
    thatHappend = true;
});


setInterval(function () {
        if (thatHappend) {
           console.log('Hey!');
           thatHappend = false;
        }
  }, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="sample"></textarea>
```

Comment: This recursion could fill up the stack. You could use setInterval instead.

Comment: Oh, since  I am not an active user of javascript, I didn't know about `setInterval`. Thanks!

Comment: @NevilleNazerane: No, it can’t.

Comment: What can't and why not? please elaborate

Comment: @NevilleNazerane: `timeout` sets a timer. It doesn’t call itself directly and will not use an unbounded amount of stack space.

Comment: Yeah got it. Even so, setinterval a simpler approach and meant for exclusively this purpose. So I updated the question with it.